# How do I pass variables and functions to an alert function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write JavaScript that will prompt a user for data, run a function to perform a calculation on that data, and then create an alert to display that data.

Currently, this code has two functions: calculateArea and displayArea:

**calculateArea**

```
function calculateArea(myRadius) {

    //sets the variable 'myArea' to radius^2 * pi
    var myArea = (myRadius * myRadius * math.pi);

    //returns the variable myArea to the global function.
    return myArea;

}
```

**displayArea**

```
function displayArea() {

    //the code for the alert
    alert("A circle with a " + myRadius + " centimeter radius has an area of " + myArea + " centimeters.");

}
```

**Expected Output:** The webpage should prompt the user for their radius, and then display an alert that shows the area calculation.

**Actual Output:** The webpage prompts the user for the radius, and the does nothing else.

Here's the body of the HTML document:

```
<body>

<script>

// Performs the calculateArea function on the myRadius variable.
function calculateArea(myRadius) {

    //sets the variable 'myArea' to radius^2 * pi
    var myArea = (myRadius * myRadius * math.pi);

    //returns the variable myArea to the global function.
    return myArea;

}

//Performs an alert that shows the area and radius of the circle.    
function displayArea() {

    //the code for the alert
    alert("A circle with a " + myRadius + " centimeter radius has an area of " + myArea + " centimeters.");

}

//prompts the user for the circle radius.
var myRadius = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the radius of your circle in centimeters: ",));

//runs the calculateArea function on the myRadius variable entered by the user.
calculateArea(myRadius);

//runs the displayArea function, showing the alert.
displayArea();

</script>


</body>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error,  remove the comma from var myRadius ... line and btw using alerts is so 90s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

- Write `Math.PI` with the exact uppper/lower case characters.
- Get the result from the calculation in some variable
- Pass variables to the second function, avoiding to rely on global variables.

Here is how it can work:

```js
function calculateArea(myRadius) {
    // Math needs a capital, and PI is all caps
    var myArea = myRadius * myRadius * Math.PI;
    return myArea;
}

// Add arguments to this function:
function displayArea(myRadius, myArea) {
    alert("A circle with a " + myRadius + " centimeter radius has an area of " + myArea + " centimeters.");
}

var myRadius = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the radius of your circle in centimeters: ",));

// store the result
var myArea = calculateArea(myRadius);
displayArea(myRadius, myArea); // pass the input and result that this function needs
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your code here.

Here's what changed:

1. `math.pi` must be capitalized as `Math.PI`
2. Just as you're storing your prompt to the `myRadius` variable, you also need to store the result of `calculateArea()` to a variable. I'm setting it to `myArea` after it finishes running.

```js
// Performs the calculateArea function on the myRadius variable.
function calculateArea(myRadius) {

  //sets the variable 'myArea' to radius^2 * pi
  var myArea = (myRadius * myRadius * Math.PI);

  //returns the variable myArea to the global function.
  return myArea;

}

//Performs an alert that shows the area and radius of the circle.    
function displayArea() {

  //the code for the alert
  alert("A circle with a " + myRadius + " centimeter radius has an area of " + myArea + " centimeters.");

}

//prompts the user for the circle radius.
var myRadius = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the radius of your circle in centimeters: ", ));

//runs the calculateArea function on the myRadius variable entered by the user.
var myArea = calculateArea(myRadius);

//runs the displayArea function, showing the alert.
displayArea();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `myArea` but not storing it somewhere and it is **Math.PI** not math.pi. as `myRadius` is defined globally you can use it in other functions as well.

```
var myArea = calculateArea(myRadius); // gets the return myArea value and defined globally
```

```html
<body>

<script>
  
// Performs the calculateArea function on the myRadius variable.
function calculateArea(myRadius) {

    //sets the variable 'myArea' to radius^2 * pi
    var myArea = (myRadius * myRadius * Math.PI);

    //returns the variable myArea to the global function.
    return myArea;

}

//Performs an alert that shows the area and radius of the circle.    
function displayArea() {

    //the code for the alert
    alert("A circle with a " + myRadius + " centimeter radius has an area of " + myArea + " centimeters.");

}

//prompts the user for the circle radius.
var myRadius = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the radius of your circle in centimeters: ",));

//runs the calculateArea function on the myRadius variable entered by the user.
var myArea = calculateArea(myRadius);

//runs the displayArea function, showing the alert.
displayArea();

</script>
```